# Failed Openshift node doesn't detach ScaleIO volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, emc

I am using kubernetes.io/scaleio provisioner with Openshift Container Platform 3.9.
When I manually shutdown a node, it doesn't detach the volumes attached to the node's assigned pods.
As a result, the new pods unable to mount those volumes on another node (ScaleIO is limited for ReadWriteOnce)

Symptom:
The new pod is stuck in "Container Creating" status and the events shows the following:
Failed Mount - MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "k8svol-xxxxxxx": Only single SDC may be mapped to this volume at a time

Has anyone encountered this issue?
Any solutions?

Comment: Are you running steps to evacuate the node, or just somehow turning the node off? https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/manage_nodes.html#evacuating-pods-on-nodes

Comment: I'm turning the node off because I want to reproduce a node faliure and I expect the platform to handle it automatically.

Comment: What storage provider are you using, on what infrastructure?

Comment: EMC ScaleIO on bare metel.